# In Buzz Aldrin's Race into Space, what does the "endurance" stat do?

Tags: buzz-aldrins-race-into-space

Every astonaut has a capsule piloting stat, which increases their chance of success during any capsule phase, a docking stat which increases their chances during any docking phase, a landing stat which increases their chances during any landing phase, and an EVA stat which increases their chances during EVA phases.  But what does the endurance stat do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual for the game has been uploaded online and can be found [here](https://www.raceintospace.org/images/manual.pdf).

On page 13, it says:

> **ENDURANCE**
>
> This skill is added to the capsule safety factor
> during space duration attempts and lunar missions.